# Consistent indentation of modules with Perl::Tidy

Tags: perl, perl-tidy

I am using Perl::Tidy and Perl::Critic while testing my software on several platforms (different Linux distributions and macOS).

I now get different formatting from Perl::Tidy on Linux and macOS which makes Perl::Critic fail because the code is not tidy.

The difference is in the indentation of arguments for used modules.

For example, on Linux (Fedora with the default Perl::Tidy v20220217):

```
use Carp;
use English qw(-no_match_vars);
use POSIX qw(uname);
use Readonly;
```

and on macOS with Perl::Tidy v20220613

```
use Carp;
use English qw(-no_match_vars);
use POSIX   qw(uname);           ## qw is indented to be aligned
use Readonly;
```

I did not find an option to define the behaviour and cannot control the version of Perl::Tidy on all the systems where the tests are run.

Is there a way to make Perl::Tidy indent these lines consistently regardless of the version? Is there a command line option that I missed?

Currently, I am just ignoring the block:

```
#<<<  Perl::Tidy indents "qw" differently on older versions
use Carp;
use English qw(-no_match_vars);
use POSIX   qw(uname);
use Readonly;
#>>>
```

But maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 20220613 version added a new option to control this alignment. From the [changelog](https://github.com/perltidy/perltidy/blob/master/CHANGES.md#2022-06-13):

> Added vertical alignment for qw quotes and empty parens in 'use' statements (see issue #git 93).  This new alignment is 'on' by default and will change formatting as shown below. If this is not wanted it can be turned off with the parameter -vxl='q' (--valign-exclusion-list='q').

> ```
> # old default, or -vxl='q'
> use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
> use Fcntl qw(O_RDONLY O_WRONLY O_EXCL O_CREAT);
> use Symbol qw(gensym);
> use Exporter ();
> ```

> ```
> # new default
> use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
> use Fcntl        qw(O_RDONLY O_WRONLY O_EXCL O_CREAT);
> use Symbol       qw(gensym);
> use Exporter     ();
> ```

So if you invoke `perltidy` with the `-vxl='q'` option on the Mac you're using, you'll get the older behavior. If this is done as part of an automated process, maybe adjust whatever is running `perltidy` to check the version first to see if the option should be included or not automatically.